# chain callback using deferred and pipe

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I am struggling to chain the callback with pipes using deferred. It seems to work just fine but in the callback2, it brings me data from callback1. Here is how the code looks like:

```
var getCall1 = function() {
    return $.ajax(url, {
        type: "GET",
        data: { },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}


var getCall2 = function () {
    return $.ajax(url, {
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

var callback1 = function (data)
            {
                alert('call 1 completed');
            };

var callback2 = function (data)
            {
                alert('call 2 completed');
            };

$.when(getCall1()).done(callBack1).pipe(getCall2()).done(callBack2);
```

What am i missing here?

--Edit--

If i break them in to two deferred calls, it works but then whats the use of chaining and pipe?

```
$.when(getCall1()).done(callBack1);
$.when(getCall2()).done(callBack2);
```

--Correct way to do this--

```
var getCall1 = function() {
    return $.ajax(url, {
        type: "GET",
        data: { },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}.pipe(function (d){return d});


var getCall2 = function () {
    return $.ajax(url, {
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}.pipe(function (d){return d});

var callback1 = function (data)
            {
                alert('call 1 completed');
            };

var callback2 = function (data)
            {
                alert('call 2 completed');
            };

        $.when(getCall1, getCall2).done(function(d1, d2){
            callback1(d1);
            callback2(d2);

        });
```

Comment: Is that typo on your sample code? (should be callback instead of the camel-case callBack)

Answer (score 0):

You should write `pipe(getCall2)`, not `pipe(getCall2())`. [deferred.pipe()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) expects a callback returning a deferred, not the deferred itself. Which makes sense, as the point is to chain requests (i.e. only start the second ajax call after the first has finished), and you only get the deferred after you started the action.

Comment: nope. thats not the problem but still if i change it, it doesnt do the expected. But i have figured it out. I will post the answer.

Comment: Not sure what you expect, but it does what you asked (second callback gets result from second ajax call): http://jsfiddle.net/qeqkg/1/

Answer (score 0):

What i understand in your code is you want to call `getCall2` only if `getCall1` successed.

So your code seems to be good. I tried it in jsFiddle (with a more simple example) and it works great for me :

> http://jsfiddle.net/PG3aN/

Maybe it's a stupid question but are you sure that getCall1 and getCall2 should not simply return the same result from server ? That could explain why you get same data in callbacks 1 and 2.

Other question, in your last code sample, you write

```
var getCall1 = function() {
return $.ajax(url, {
        type: "GET",
        data: { },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}.pipe(function (d){return d});
```

Does the last pipe change something on your code behaviour ?

And a last remark about your last code sample, the expected result is not the same. In this code you wrote that you will call callback1 and callback2 only if both getCall1 and getCall2 successed. Which is not the same behaviour as your first code.

**Edit** : a new jsFiddle with real asynchronous result

> http://jsfiddle.net/PG3aN/1/

Comment: Well, the last snippet you see is the solution i figured out. If i dont use it, it returns me the first response in both the callbacks.

Comment: Are you sure the problem does not reside in your second ajax call ? We have tried your example with sequential pipes with no issues about it. Calling pipe(e) { return e; } is just like doing nothing. So i don't knoww how it could be the solution.

See ["chain tasks" example in jQuery pipe documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/). It uses ajax -> pipe -> ajax -> done which is really similar to your needs.

Comment: I am sure it is working as i wanted it to after i changed to code as shown in the second snippet

Comment: Ok great, i just wanted to be sure you understood that doing `when(g1).done(c1).pipe(g2).done(c2)` is absolutely not the same behaviour as doing `when(g1, g2).done(c1, c2)`.