# How to chain multiple group of animations in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have several functions where I do some kind of animations and some other things:

```
function animations1() {
    $('some_object').animation();
    ...
}

function animations2() {
    $('some_object').animation();
    ...
}

function animations3() {
    $('some_object').animation();
    ...
}
```

What would be the best way to chain these functions, e.i. call `animations2` when `animations1` is completed, and call `animations3`, when `animations2` is completed?

Comment: If you were to just invoke all three functions immediately, jQuery's effects queue would make sure that the animations execute in sequence (instead of all at once).

Comment: @amnotiam, not really, jQuery will try to animate them all "at the same time"

Comment: @Adnan: Not if the same selector is used as shown in the question.

Comment: @amnotiam, yep. True, didn't notice that they're use the same selector. Thanks

Comment: An example of how they run in sequence and not parallel: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sf4bK/

Comment: The same selector isn't used... I do animations with several objects at the same time inside each function. So @Raminson answer isn't correct in this case...

Comment: @Levani, on the contrary. Since you're using different selectors, Raminson's answer is your best bet here.

Comment: @Adnan, Yes maybe, after adding the second example.

Comment: and what about jquery deferred object? I was trying to use that method before asking this question but could manage to chain multiple function easily.

Comment: @Levani, I found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PG3aN/) in my bookmarks. Edit: After googling the link I found that it belongs to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9946447/1105514)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the callback function of animate method:

```
$('some_object').animate({..}, 100, function(){
   $('another_object').animate({..}, 100)
})
```

or:

```
function animations1() {
     $('some_object').animate({..}, 100, function(){
       animations2() 
     })
}

function animations2() {
     $('another_object').animate({..}, 100, function(){
       animations3() 
     })
}

function animations3() {
    $('some_object').animation();
    ...
}
```

Comment: *"Lets say I have several functions..."*

Comment: With your edit, you're assuming the same sequence is always desired. I'm guessing they're in separate functions for a reason.

Comment: @amnotiam, while you have a completely valid point, OP didn't make his case really clear.

Comment: @Adnan: You're right. The actual situation is entirely unclear.

Comment: @Raminson: FYI, this would be a little more concise... `$('another_object').animate({..}, 100, animations3)`